# Which monsters have immunity or resistance to non-silvered non-magical weapons?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, weapons, damage-resistance, immunities

The *Player's Handbook* (p. 148) (and the Basic Rules) state about [silvered weapons](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/equipment#SilveredWeapons):

> Some monsters that have immunity or resistance to nonmagical weapons are susceptible to silver weapons [...]

**Which monsters have immunity or resistance to non-silvered non-magical weapons?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Resistance to Non-Silvered Non-Magical Weapons

- Amnizu (MTF)
- Bael (MTF)
- Barbed Devil
- Bearded Devil
- Black Abishai (MTF)
- Blue Abishai (MTF)
- Bone Devil
- Chain Devil
- Deathlock (MTF)
- Deathlock Mastermind (MTF)
- Erinyes
- Geryon (MTF)
- Green Abishai (MTF)
- Hellfire Engine (MTF)
- Horned Devil
- Hutijin (MTF)
- Ice Devil
- Imp
- Merregon (MTF)
- Moloch (MTF)
- Narzugon (MTF)
- Night Hag
- Nupperibo (MTF)
- Orthon (MTF)
- Pit Fiend
- Red Abishai (MTF)
- Spined Devil
- Titivilus (MTF)
- Warlock of the Fiend (VGM)
- White Abishai (MTF)
- Wight
- Wraith
- Zariel (MTF)

### Immunity to Non-Silvered Non-Magical Weapons

- Jackalwere
- Lycanthrope (Werebear, wereboar, wererat, weretiger, werewolf)
- Yeth Hound (VGM)

---

*Note: Most of these are devils, fiends, or undead.*

#### Legend

Unless otherwise indicated by the abbreviations below, the monsters above are listed in the Monster Manual.

MTF = Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes

VGM = Volo's Guide to Monsters

Comment: +1 for taking the time to dig all of this up from 3 different books...

Comment: [D&D Beyond search](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters?filter-resistance=14&filter-search=&filter-type=0) finds a few more with resistance. I don't have the books to verify.

Comment: @MichałPolitowski thanks, I added the deathlock, Moloch, and orthon.